# Can I allow users to update their registration?

Tags: civievent

I have a non-profit that runs an event once a month where the users leave their cars at home to walk, bike, or ride public transit for their daily commute. I'm testing the online registration function of CiviCRM to allow them to record their transit method and mileage for that day, but they need to be able to update the record in case their method changes. For example, if they said they were going to ride a bike but instead took the subway because of rain.

If they attempt to register twice they'll get the message that they're already registered. If I allow multiple participants, they can record a new route but they show up as multiple entries with the same name (obviously).

I can't seem to find a configuration setting to allow registration updates. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Drupal Webforms currently have this functionality, so if you set up your Civi event registration page using Drupal Webform-Integration, your users will be able to revisit the form and update their contact info, registration details, or even cancel their registration.

Comment: This looks like the right solution and may be useful for other functionality we're working on. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

This feature is being discussed as part of this [Make It Happen](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen) initiative: [Self service view, update and cancel for CiviEvent](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen/self-service-view-update-and-cancel-civievent).

Answer (score 1):

To my mind you haven't given enough detail about how you intend to set up your events.

If the method of transportation is built into the actual event registration  (that is people register to ride a bike , or they register to catch the train, or they register to walk) then they won't be able to change their registration for the event if they used a different mode of transport.

However, you could set it up so that people register to participate in the alternative transport event and then collect details on their proposed mode of transport via custom fields.  Once the event is over you can send them a personalised (checksum) link to a profile containing those custom fields and they can update them if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent blog post about this Make It Happen that davidjenx refers to:
https://civicrm.org/blog/zorga-lina/civievent-self-service-canceltransfer-for-participant

You said that allowing multiple participants was one approach you had tested, but which obviously led to 2 listings. One approach might be to allow multiple participants, and then try to dedupe them or only show the latest of the bookings.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on JoAnne's answer: You can expose the profile you used to collect the information (using custom fields) during the event registration and participants can edit their information using that profile.

On the profile page, click More. Click on "Use Profile-Create mode". Copy that url, change the create to edit. Then share that with participants, using checksum or simply a link (that will require them to login).

Answer (score 1):

This extension lets participants update their registration: [edit event fee](https://civicrm.org/extensions/edit-event-fee). It basically exposes the form that is available in the backend (with some access restrictions, or checksum validation).

It has not yet been tested with completed payments, only with pending payments.