# Can Attendees Modify their Registration?

Tags: civievent

Can attendees access their registration and make changes after they've submitted a completed registration?

Comment: There may be some useful information in my related question here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/recommended-process-for-credit-card-additions-edits-to-event-registrations

Answer (score 3):

This is not out-of-the box functionality. Have a look at these threads:

[Recommended process for credit card additions/'edits' to event registrations?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/recommended-process-for-credit-card-additions-edits-to-event-registrations)

[Can I allow users to update their registration?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/can-i-allow-users-to-update-their-registration/3937)