# Event part payment & multiple registration

Tags: civievent, online-registration

We run courses that has different modules. For example

- Module A
- Module B
- Module c

A participant can chose to attend Module A now and pay.

But couple of months down the line would want to sign up for Module B or C.

Issue I am facing is when registering online for 2nd time, its coming up with a message saying "Oops! You have already registered for this course".
Is there a way to solve this problem using civievent please?

PS:We cannot use contribution due to policy within organisation not to mix course payments & donation.

Comment: Can you do each Module as a separate EVent, and/or can webform help you (if i recall you are on drupal) eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/can-i-allow-users-to-update-their-registration

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to create an event page using webform. But although I have set a price for the event the page does not give option to add payment processor. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Tapash,

I believe CiviCRM allows one to register for same event with same email address multiple times, if the setting 'Same email address?' under 'Online Registration' is enabled for the event.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Although it works for online registration, from backend it still doesn't allow to register.

Comment: Then it should be an bug in CiviCRM if you can replicate it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Please create an issue on https://lab.civicrm.org if so.